# what is the Difference between single class diagram and one class diagram per package during diagram creation in eclipse modeling juno

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, modeling

what is the Difference between single class diagram and one class diagram per package during diagram creation in eclipse modeling [juno developer tool].

Comment: Other than the obvious difference in amount of information visible at once in a large project with many packages?

Answer (score 0):

Which Juno build have you downloaded ? I will try it and report if I get the link.
I didn't know that Juno had an UML editor available.